# SVG PATH Creation is not creating in exact path using mouse XY Co ordinates

Tags: svg, canvas

I am drawing the SVG Path using XY Coordinates of element and mouse move. SVG path is not appending with correct Mouse point.

This is my code snippet

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" >
<g><path id=""></path></g> </svg>
<script>
.
.
.
     var coord = getMousePosition(evt);
     var getpos = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
     var CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
     var pathValue = "M "+getpos.x+" "+getpos.y+" "+coord.x+" "+coord.y;
     document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("d", pathValue);
.
.

</script>
```

.........

Comment: please create a runnable example ideally using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missed the 'L' command of your svg path...

```js
let path;

addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  svg.innerHTML += `<path 
      fill=none 
      stroke-width=5 
      stroke="hsl(${Math.random()*360},66%,66%)" 
      d="M${e.x},${e.y}"
  />`;
  path = svg.querySelector('path:last-child');
})

addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  path = null;
})

addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  path && path.setAttribute('d', path.getAttribute('d') + `L${e.x},${e.y}`);
})

addEventListener('resize', function() {
  svg.setAttribute('width', innerWidth);
  svg.setAttribute('height', innerHeight);
})

dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg id=svg></svg>
```

Click "Run code snippet" and try to draw in snippet frame ...